# Nifi flow deleted when restarting sandbox VM

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi, hortonworks-sandbox

I upgraded my nifi from 0.6.0, the version that comes together with Hortonworks HDF, to the latest version 0.7.0.  I followed the upgrade steps as mentioned here. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Upgrading+NiFi

However, whenever I restart the HDP VM, my nifi flow is gone, and i have to redo it.  I noticed that the file size in ../configuration_resources/flow.xml.gz becomes 0 everytime I restart VM.  Did I miss anything on the upgrade?

Comment: How did you initially install NiFi 0.6.0? Was it by manually extracting the tar/zip, or using Ambari?

Comment: I installed HDF from Hortonworks (which contains NiFi 0.6.0) into HDP.  Then I upgraded NiFi to 0.7.0 and followed the instructions from apache site.

Comment: Ok I can't think of why it would reset flow.xml.gz... just to understand a little more about your setup, you have /opt/nifi-0.7.0/conf/nifi.properties with a value of nifi.flow.configuration.file=/opt/configuration_resources/flow.xml.gz ? and you can see that file has data in it while creating the flow, but then it is erased on restart of the VM?

Comment: i installed 0.7.0 inside "/root/hdf/HDF-1.2.0.1-1/" directory where my previous nifi is installed (as part of HDF installation process). since I place the configuration_resources outside the nifi-0.7.0 directory, i set the nifi.flow.configuration.file to "../configuration_resources/flow.xml.gz". i think there's no issue on that one because when i restart the nifi, i still am able to view my flow... only when I restart the VM than the flow.xml.gz resets to 0... as a workaround, i make sure i backup the flow and when I restart vm, i take the backup flow from the archive directory.

Comment: Interesting, it must be something specific to the VM... if you shutdown NiFi first and then restart the VM, does it also reset flow.xml.gz? or is it only when you restart the VM while NiFi is running?